# Query SQL and get the result direct to .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a mp3 player in aspx page like this:

```
<a href="#" class="jp-play"></a>
<a href="#" class="jp-pause"></a>
<a href="#" class="jp-prev">Previous Track</a>
<a href="#" class="jp-next">Next Track</a>
<a href="#" class="jp-more-songs">Listen to More Songs</a>
```

and database store path to .mp3 files. Is there anyway to read database then assign them to "#" automatically?

Comment: What are those `href` ? Hyperlinks?

Comment: yes are they anchor tags ? like `<a href="#" ></a>`

Comment: I've edited your question. Take a look through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you have problems formatting your question.

Comment: One step at a time.  Are you able to query the database and get the paths without using your c# code?

Comment: There are lots of ways but you do not have enough detail in your question. It depends how you want to access the database (from the HTML or from the code behind) and whether you want to use things like jQuery to manipulate the anchors.

meda's answer is correct but might not be complete depending on whether you display multiple MP3s on the same page (in which case, you could use a repeater control) or you could write a datagrid of the details into the page make it invisible and wire up your anchors with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `Id` and `runat` attribute to your anchor tag like this

```
<a href="#" id="play" runat="server" class="jp-play">Play</a>
```

then you will be able to access it in code behind

```
play.HRef = "http://www.example.com/test.mp3";
```

Answer (score 0):

generally that kind of paths are used in html5 with pushState() integration

you can easily implement it using [jquery](http://jquery-plugins.net/pronto-jquery-plugin-for-faster-page-loads) plugins and a lot of other js frameworks like ember.js, backbone.js, angular.js among many others!

Comment: I don't see how client-side javascript helps server-side operations (judging by the other answer).

Comment: js frameworks easily help you to perform ajax calls in the server side if you want a full refresh on your page by the time you click on play and pause go for it, it´s up to you, but in these days is more common to see SPA since they are a looooooot better in terms of user experience, I guess it could be the case of myUrl#play, myUrl#pause, myUrl#stop